# doctrine 2: inheritance mapping join with parent table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a base table like this:

```
class BaseProduct 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="baseProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="menu_category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
    protected $category;
// ...
```

and another entity that inherit from BaseProduct

```
class ChildProduct extends BaseProduct
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="childProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="menu_category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
    protected $category;
```

and Category entity:

```
class Category 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\BaseProduct", mappedBy="category")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position"= "ASC"})
     */
    private $baseProducts;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\ChildProduct", mappedBy="category")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position"= "ASC"})
     */
    private $childProducts;
```

My `ChildProduct` table has one column named `id` and referenced to `BaseProduct` id's. Now I want to join Category with `ChildProduct` with this query:

```
    $qb->select('mc', 'cp')
        ->from('ProductBundle:Category', 'mc')
        ->leftJoin('mc.childProducts', 'cp')
        // .....
```

when I execute this query it gives this error:

> ContextErrorException in SqlWalker.php line 922:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: childProducts

While I have `childProducts` in Category.

Now I have two questions:

1. am I able to query on a parent field that does not exists in child table.
2. what's wrong with my query

Comment: Have you tried running `doctrine:schema:validate`?

Comment: yes I have, but didn't help

Comment: Should the `$baseProducts` `OneToMany` annotation reference the *BaseProduct* entity instead? Not sure why that would cause this error, but it doesn't look right.

Comment: it's correct in my code. it was just a typo when posting qustion.

Answer (score 0):

Check doctrine chapter Inheritance Mapping: [Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Following the documentation try this (I didn't test the code)

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class BaseProduct 
{
    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="baseProducts")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="menu_category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
     protected $category;
```

Now Doctrine knows that your class is a base class for others. 
All you have to do it extend base class and add annotation `@ORM\Entity`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 **/
class ChildProduct extends BaseProduct
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="childProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="menu_category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
    **/
    protected $category;
```

I think you can remove from ChildProduct `$category` field. It should work also.